# how to make npm shrinkwrap use custom registry in the resolved field

Tags: npm, artifactory, npm-install

I have a configured npm proxy repository on my artifactory. Still, when I execute npm shrinkwrap, some of the dependencies get resolved from https://registry.npmjs.org.
this cause my build to fail when the build server does not have internet access.

Is there a way to force npm shrinkwrap to resolve all dependencies (including transitive) to be resolved from my artifactory repository?

(note: each npm module in my project has .npmrc file with a registry key that points to artifactory)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, the issue is that some dependencies are being resolved directly from the NPM.org repo. Is that correct?

If so, have you tried using NPM virtual repository in Artifactory and check the "Enable Dependency Rewrite" checkbox under the virtual repository configuration --> Advance tab?

Comment: Yes, this is the issue and No I haven't. tried it. I wanted to know if there something I can do from npm side before I change anything in artifactory.

Comment: Not AFAIK. NPM is going to Artifactory as you instructed it. The thing is that some packages have the external dependencies hard coded, and for that reason Artifactory has this feature. This is the best approach imo.

Answer (score 1):

Checking **Enable Dependency Rewrite** on the Artifactory Virtual repository's advanced tab definitely works.

- We executed a shrinkwrap prior to setting this and saw **registry.npmjs.org** in the shrinkwrap file
- We repeated after setting **Enable Dependency Rewrite** and see our artifactory host and uri in the shrinkwrap file

(I would have commented but presently lack the rep to do so)